# FB like button shows on page, but not popup on same page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

Created a script quite a while back which worked perfectly fine until I noticed this problem the other day.  The FB like button is shown on the actual page and works fine... I then also have a share button on the page which shows a pop up with other sharing services... in this popup I also show the SAME fb like button.

Both the page and popup locations use the exact same code :

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="'+ encodeURL(fb_url()) +'" data-action="'+ settings.fbAction +'" data-colorscheme="'+ settings.fbcolorscheme +'" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="97" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Variables and functions are correct.  This works fine on the actual page and worked fine on both the page and popup until recently... so I guess my question is if there was something changed where you can only show one instance of the same like button on a page?  This is the only thing I can think of, but wondering if perhaps anyone else came across something similar.  I am pretty baffled as the same code never had a problem until recently.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to render multiple like buttons with the same `data-href` value within the same HTML document. Please check that your `<div class="fb-like"/>` elements are part of the DOM before loading the Facebook Javascript SDK like so:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Note that if you include YOUR_APP_ID and have the `xfbml=1` set (as per the query string-like appendix in the example above), then the Like Buttons will be rendered upon completion of the SDK loading. Any Like Buttons added after this point will not be rendered (perhaps if they were added to the DOM via Javascript, jQuery or similar - for example after an AJAX call).

If you **must** add the second Like Button to the DOM after the loading of the SDK, calling `FB.init()` after your addition to the DOM will render any Like Buttons yet to be rendered, like so:

```
FB.init({
    appId:'YOUR_APP_ID', 
    xfbml:true
});
```

Beware: This works, but is not recommended as the following warning message will print to your console:

> FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem.